# Mail server Mac OS X Snow leopard

Tags: mac-osx, smtp, email, osx-snow-leopard

I have a problem, I can't find at good tutorial how to setup my mail server.  I only can get a user account with the "shortname" and my server's ip, address like nickname@10.0.1.100 :/

I need to bind more domains on this mail server and login with order domain names

I hope you can provide information about running a mail server on Mac OS X.  Please provide links to any good tutorials or other reference materials.

Answer (score 1):

See Apple's [Mail Service Administration](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Mail_Service_Admin_v10.6.pdf) as well as their other Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server [documentation](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/documentation.html). Also, Topicdesk.com has excellent [tutorials](http://osx.topicdesk.com/content/category/4/18/41/) including one for [tuning postfix](http://osx.topicdesk.com/content/view/38/41/) and one for [Making Virtual Mail Users in OS X 10.4/10.5 Server](http://osx.topicdesk.com/content/view/45/41/), but the latter hasn't been updated for Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server yet and I haven't checked to see if Apple has improved that area of their Mail services. Worth a read though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider getting an Os X Snow Leopard [Server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/mail-services.html)

I think it will make your life easier, but if you won't/can't then you must be aware by now that Os X includes a [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html) in the default installation. There is a [basic tutorial](http://www.postfix.org/basic.html) on how to configure it that might be helpful to you.

Comment: Hai, i have a OSX Server licens home to Snow Leopard. my problem now its i can't get my mail server to work right whit vhost and that.